# Application Insights "server response time" metric - can I exclude certain requests?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have a web application which makes use of SignalR. Some SignalR connections are using the "server send events" protocol. This results in very long running web requests e.g. signalr/connect which execute as long as the connection is open.
This skews the "server response time" metric and makes it impossible to set an alert on it.
Is there any way to filter out certain requests from this metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Controlling the Data

Yes, you can do this. If you want those requests not to be included in the requests at all then just remove the telemetry information from the header for those requests. If you have the telemetry sitting in a master page, then you will have to remove it from there and add to individual pages, where you want.

If you want more granular control then you can control and trigger the telemetry javascript yourself. You can have the long running requests run via Ajax separately and not affecting the telemetry data. Then you can have alerts as you require.

#### Additionally, controlling the View of the Data

If you just want to filter while viewing then follow these steps:

- Open the Application Insights blade.
- Then navigate or click on the "**Server Response Time**" metric from your dashboard.
- Then Click on the ***Filters*** button in the "**Server Responses**" blade.
- Expand the filter for "**Request Name**" and select checkbox for only the requests you want.
- Click **Update** once you are done with the filters.

[image]